# NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 for few seconds after app start up

Tags: ios, ios9, afnetworking, alamofire

I'm getting "NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004" error with Alamofire API calls,
but **only for few seconds after app started** (or took a rest for few minutes while the app's opened and make a call after that)

If I try to make the same call after few seconds, everything works fine.
I searched all the Stack Overflow questions and checked all the possible causes below:

1. No problem with Internet connection
2. "App Transport Security Settings" are correct and server's using https (I also tried "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=true" but that didn't help)
3. APIs working fine

My gut feeling is that getting the network settings takes few seconds and when I make an API call before that's done, it just fails immediately. OR.. I'm using a Websocket in background that could be related?

> FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x137d39380 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb341a9f540000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2200, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[FILTERED], NSErrorFailingURLKey=[FILTERED], _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2200, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

Any suggestions?

***UPDATED***

Found that app makes 4 requests on launch, and 1 or 2 of them randomly fails, and I checked Nginx access and error log and there's no log for the failed calls at all.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue as I'm upgrading my networking libs from AFNetworking 2.x to 3.x. Please let me know if you come up with a solution to the problem. So far I have also confirmed that ssl negotiation is taking place which indicates that "could not connect to the server" is not the real cause. I've also tried turning off ATS and certificate pinning. Everything starts working after a minute or 2 but the first several requests fail.

Comment: Has anyone figured out whats wrong in the end? I have the same problem... :(

Comment: @BartoszHernas, what version of nginx are you running? We have the same issue here with nginx 1.10, iOS 9.3.1 using HTTP/2 with TLS 1.2. The issue goes away with HTTP/1.1. We can see in Wireshark that the app only connects once, which is successful, yet the first request fails.

Comment: @AdrianSchönig you are totally right... have the same problem, downgrading now all my servers to nginx 1.9.14

Comment: I don't have access to my server environment, but I solved it using a delay (100-200ms) for the request calling.

Comment: How can I fix this when I don't have access to the server's environment? I also see `HTTP/1.1` in the response header, but still receive the `-1004` error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have the same issue here with Nginx 1.10.0 (and 1.9.15), iOS 9.3.1 using HTTP/2 with TLS 1.2.

The issue goes away with HTTP/1.1 and it's also working with HTTP/2 in Nginx version up to 1.9.14.

Comment: I am using nginx/1.9.12 on production and nginx/1.9.15 on staging. 

I can confirm what you are saying, do you have any idea why is it happening?
Have you opened an issue for nginx?

Comment: Yes, it's marked as a duplicate of this issue: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/959

Comment: Oh, great thanks for this info! I've spent 2 days to find the solution. I've tried many App Transport Security settings, http libs and others.

Answer (score 6):

Nginx 1.11.0 Mainline is now available with the fix included mentioned earlier in this topic;

> Change: HTTP/2 clients can now start sending request body
>          immediately; the "http2_body_preread_size" directive controls size of
>          the buffer used before nginx will start reading client request body.

I tested it and for me this release now works correctly again.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a confirmed bug in nginx 1.10. An issue about it can be found on the bug tracker of nginx at https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/979. The actual issue can be found at https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/959

You might want to consider switching to the 1.9 branch which has releases which do work. Hopefully nginx will release a 1.10.1 version soon which does not have this bug.

The issue actually only occurs on iOS; Android, Windows and OSX itself seem to have no problems negotiating a valid http2 connection.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this issue? Or should I revert back to nginx 1.9.14?

Comment: Reverting back would help. However this is not the stable branch. Reverting back to 1.8.1 would give you spdy access again. Apple did mark the bug as confirmed by now though

Answer (score 2):

I can also confirm that the nginx 1.9.15 not works correctly. Some calls always got "Could not connect to the server", and after revert to nginx 1.9.12 everything works fine.

Comment: i have the same issue in 1.9.15 too

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps that I would try to follow:

- 1) test my app in the simulator and device
- 2) look if https is really needed instead of http
- 3) configure an alamofire manager and change timeout (for this step i
  write some code):

  ```
  var alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance    
  let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
  configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10
  configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
  configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource =  30
  alamofireManager.delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = nil
  ```

(so whit this last step the next alamofire calls can be for example: `alamofireManager.request(etc....`)

- 4) test with hard link like http://www.google.com, if the same thing
  dont happened nothing around your swift code are incorrect, try to
  set your web server parameters..

Comment: 1. Tested in both simulator and few devices, and results are the same

Comment: 2. https is really needed, 3. Tried that, didn't fix

Comment: 4. Tried with a hard link "https://google.com" and it didn't happen. Maybe there're some issues with Nginx or the webserver. I'll have a look. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!!

versions:

```
1. Nginx version: 1.10.2
2. IOS version: 9.3.2
```

When the config like this:

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

Have the same problem like you.

But !!!

When the config like this:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
```

Problem solved!!