# AFNetworking 3.0 iOS 9.3.5 reject some SSL

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking, ios10, ios9.3

This happened only in iOS 9.3.5 (not sure about other 9 or below), not occur in iOS 10.x.

When I use AFNetworking to connect to an API URL, it just run into failure callback with error like below:

> LOG: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to
>   the server." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=APIURL,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2200, NSErrorFailingURLKey=APIURL, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x16146990 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length =
>   16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb253ce7160000000000000000},
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2200}}}

When I paste the API to safari browser (same device), it ask me to trust a certificate or something like that, so I'm afraid there's something wrong in the configuration in the app.

My call for URL:

```
self.sessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseUrl sessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
self.sessionManager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
self.sessionManager.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;
self.sessionManager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = timeout;
self.sessionManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

// Call API:
[self.sessionManager POST:path parameters:dictParams progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) { 
    // success block
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSError *error) {
    // failure block
}
```

I've even set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=true` in `App Transport Security Settings` inside `info.plist`.

How to fix this? I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907767/nsurlerrordomain-code-1004-for-few-seconds-after-app-start-up?noredirect=1&lq=1) have the similar error, but I'm not so sure. I don't have access to the API host and in ios 10.x it works just fine. When using postman it works too.